# What's this compression method?

Tags: package, compression

I want to modify a file in [this](https://www.mediafire.com/?sqgt6qkku5iqph1) package, but I can't compress it with the same method that was used before (on another PC). Anyone can give me a piece of advice how to compress it and with which software? For example I want to edit the scripts\alienware_light_fx.xml file and then compress the whole package again.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english! :(

Comment: this is an apple macintosh osx compression

Comment: Any idea how to compress the files with that method? I am using Windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a zip file. Any zip utility can create or modify it. You don't need to recompress the whole thing. A zip utility will allow you to simply replace that one entry.